# Return Maximum Value Below Certain Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, max

I need to populate the CalvingDate field in the below "Production Inputs" table to calculate the DIM.

Production Inputs

| CowID | ProductionDate | DateCalved | DaysInMilk [DIM] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18001 | 08/10/2021 | 23/02/2021 | 168 |
| 17158 | 30/10/2021 | ???? | ??? |
| 17158 | 23/10/2021 | 01/10/2021 | 23 |
| 17158 | 16/10/2021 | 01/10/2021 | 15 |
| 17158 | 08/10/2021 | 01/10/2021 | 7 |
| 17158 | 07/08/2021 | 07/08/2020 | 365 |

I have a table with the list of calving dates per animal

Calving Dates

| CowID | DateCalved |
| --- | --- |
| 18001 | 23/02/2021 |
| 17158 | 01/10/2021 |
| 17158 | 07/08/2020 |

The basic logic is to choose the DateCalved that is closest to the ProductionDate but that is before the ProductionDate. Considering Line #3: My Sudo-code would be: "Give me the Maximum Value of all Calving Dates for CowID 17158 smaller than Production Date 30/10/2021"

How could this be achieved using SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

> ```
> create table ProductionInputs (
>  CowID int,
>  ProductionDate date,
>  DateCalved Date,
>  DaysInMilk int
> );
>
> create table CalvingDates (
>  CowID int,
>  DateCalved Date
> );
>
> insert into ProductionInputs 
> (CowID, ProductionDate) values
> (18001,   '2021-10-08'),
> (17158, '2021-10-30'),
> (17158,   '2021-10-23'),
> (17158,   '2021-10-16'),
> (17158,   '2021-10-08'),
> (17158,   '2021-08-07');
>
> insert into CalvingDates 
> (CowID, DateCalved) values
> (18001, '2021-04-23'),
> (17158, '2021-10-01'),
> (17158, '2020-08-07');
> ```

Update statement

> ```
> UPDATE t
> SET t.DateCalved = ca.DateCalved
>   , t.DaysInMilk = DATEDIFF(day, ca.DateCalved, t.ProductionDate) 
> FROM ProductionInputs t
> CROSS APPLY (
>   SELECT MAX(d.DateCalved) AS DateCalved
>   FROM CalvingDates d 
>   WHERE d.CowId = t.CowId
>     AND d.DateCalved <= t.ProductionDate
> ) ca
> ```

Result

> ```
> select * from ProductionInputs;
> ```
>
> ```
> CowID | ProductionDate | DateCalved | DaysInMilk
> ----: | :------------- | :--------- | ---------:
> 18001 | 2021-10-08     | 2021-04-23 |        168
> 17158 | 2021-10-30     | 2021-10-01 |         29
> 17158 | 2021-10-23     | 2021-10-01 |         22
> 17158 | 2021-10-16     | 2021-10-01 |         15
> 17158 | 2021-10-08     | 2021-10-01 |          7
> 17158 | 2021-08-07     | 2020-08-07 |        365
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=19dc5ac7ec4516ffd62d478dde55d96e)*